# Amcharts4 legend label not truncated when value is right aligned

Tags: legend, amcharts, amcharts4, legend-properties

I am creating a pie chart with the legend at the bottom. I have added the config to truncate the legend label by passing

```
chart.legend.labels.template.maxWidth = 120;
chart.legend.labels.template.truncate = true;
```

Works fine until i try to right align the value by passing

```
chart.legend.valueLabels.template.align = "right";
```

After adding this, the labels are not truncated and occupy the full width.

[image: Legend label is not truncated even though it exceeds the max width]

Any help on how to achieve both truncating and also having the values aligned to the right would be much appreciated. Also I could not find any `adapter` method to overwrite the label. If so, I can strip the label after certain characters and return.

Here is a [codepen demo](https://codepen.io/Pragatheeswaran/pen/QWjwNer) of the above mentioned issue.

Comment: Your codepen link shows the labels truncated, isn't it?

Comment: The amcharts team have fixed the issue and hence the labels in the codepen looks truncated.

Answer (score 0):

It was an [issue](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/2338) acknowledged by the amcharts team and it was fixed later.